# Am I decrypting this correctly?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, tls1.2, phpseclib

Given the following inputs:

```
CLIENT RANDOM : 61fc160e0a6e96db43aebcca55da7fbccb97cc04d59fcc105490b4396a915ab9
SERVER RANDOM : f0ecb127db6e353a2985894c123532a8d092fafcf7cdce3a444f574e47524401
PREMASTER KEY : 0303ec4418e91f0abf9a012f524b61c0312008641ebce76d68b2417447e3d9a970d02fd65a20e5e3e98413dbd13b6536
```

First I use these input to calculate the following key buffers:

```
CLIENT MAC: 500c7c6e6101cb1693b4cee7db6fb0bc2725deca
SERVER MAC: 41e260280fe213bd5f2c0412c69389cac2e39e4f
CLIENT KEY: c17226212f6195c1515602a0c0864ec90e73e7bcd05ad90b196fd5a5cb2445f2
SERVER KEY: 6b07166b634a7e58e623b969eb0c024a1e866bc2719c054e1a05849b87ccf79b
CLIENT IV: dac71f7b3639cf4d4ec86ee51b9530f6
SERVER IV: c1212631365432c8d5a4c93f6f999a8e
```

I calculate these values using helper functions I found online:

```
function p_hash($algo, $secret, $seed, $size) {
    $output = "";
    $a = $seed;
    while (strlen($output) < $size) {
        $a = hash_hmac($algo, $a, $secret, true);
        $output .= hash_hmac($algo, $a . $seed, $secret, true);
    }
    return substr($output, 0, $size);
}

function prf_tls12($secret, $label, $seed, $size) {
    return p_hash("sha256", $secret, $label . $seed, $size);
}

function generate_master($pre_master_secret, $client_random, $server_random) {
    return prf_tls12($pre_master_secret, 'master secret', $client_random . $server_random, 48);
}

$client_random = hex2bin('61fc160e0a6e96db43aebcca55da7fbccb97cc04d59fcc105490b4396a915ab9');
$server_random = hex2bin('f0ecb127db6e353a2985894c123532a8d092fafcf7cdce3a444f574e47524401');
$pre_master_secret = hex2bin('0303ec4418e91f0abf9a012f524b61c0312008641ebce76d68b2417447e3d9a970d02fd65a20e5e3e98413dbd13b6536');

$master_secret = generate_master($pre_master_secret, $client_random, $server_random);

$key_buffer = prf_tls12($master_secret, 'key expansion', $server_random . $client_random, 136);

$client_mac = substr($key_buffer, 0, 20);
$server_mac = substr($key_buffer, 20, 20);
$client_key = substr($key_buffer, 40, 32);
$server_key = substr($key_buffer, 72, 32);
$client_iv = substr($key_buffer, 104, 16);
$server_iv = substr($key_buffer, 120, 16);
```

Here I have an AES_256_CBC encrypted message sent from the CLIENT ---> SERVER in Hex format

```
$EncryptedMessage = 'f32da333a3416888d55c583c9796f8fc498895e386616a62aa364a41cd2bfc203c1f296b4afd9c4a9674c993bf0db558de0c0cb2b3dc4b083af3824e0b9a3327';
```

I run the following code using the PHPSECLIB v3.0 plugin:

```
$cipher = new AES('cbc');
$cipher->setIV($client_iv);
$cipher->setKey($client_key);
$cipher->disablePadding();
$DecryptedMessage = bin2hex($cipher->decrypt(hex2bin($EncryptedMessage)));
print($DecryptedMessage);
```

I get the following output in Hex:

```
f889ff0ce7cc744c2182363e7117ae74e34ccb0510099e7c11133c369f98468de9f20fa6e7207c8121484a9663929d1af4bffb5410da37029aa26b9298411e3b
```

Basically, I have no idea whether I'm doing this right or not.  I dont seem to see anything in my decrypted message.  Also, unless I specifically use the `$cipher->disablePadding();` I will get a PHP Fatal Error saying that `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught phpseclib3\Exception\BadDecryptionException: The ciphertext has an invalid padding length (81) compared to the block size (16)`
Note: This is supposed to be an "Encrypted Handshake Message" sent as the first message from a client to server after the Key Exchange using TLS 1.2.  I am unable to determine if my decryption is correct, since I cant find much on the structure of value anywhere.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Anything you need to add you must add by using the "edit" button of your question.  As you can see, code in the comments is not easy to read

Comment: didnt see the edit button there fixed the question